# What is the best way to implement a bottom navigation bar in Flutter that has custom icons and is persistent across multiple screens?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I am working on a Flutter app and would like to implement a bottom navigation bar that is persistent across multiple screens. However, I want to customize the icons in the navigation bar and ensure that it works well with the rest of my app's design. I'm not sure where to start or what packages to use.

By "persistence across multiple screens," I mean that I want the bottom navigation bar to be visible on all screens in my app, not just the home screen. I know that this can be achieved with the help of packages like the BottomNavigationBar widget, but I want to make sure that the implementation works smoothly and doesn't cause any performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple and practical bottom navigation bar sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _screens = [
    HomeScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
    SettingsScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: _screens[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Home Screen'),
    );
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Profile Screen'),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Settings Screen'),
    );
  }
}
```

but you can use several packages available on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) that provide customizable, bottom navigation bars for Flutter apps.
such as **ff_navigation_bar** or **curved_navigation_bar**

Answer (score 0):

Use `builder` in the `MaterialApp`, assign a widget that shows the bottom nav bar with the dynamic widget (whatever route user is going).

Also there are plenty of options to get started with bottom nav bar in flutter check [this](https://fluttergems.dev/bottom-navigation-bar/)

Example of builder:

- `MaterialApp` Config

  ```
  return MaterialApp(
    ...
    ...
    builder: (context, child) => AppTemplate(child),
    ...
  );
  ```
- `AppTemplate`

  ```
  class AppTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
    final Widget? child;
    const AppTemplate(this.child, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: child,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  ```